# How to create view popup that can be swiped up to fullscreen?

Tags: java, android

I mean popup like telegram media attachemnt selection. Which opens only on part of screen, but can be swiped up to top and change to fullscreen.

[image: Popup like this]

Is there native view for this, or I must implemnt such funtionality myself? I'm writing native android app on Java.

Comment: Have you tried `Modal bottom sheet`?

Comment: Nope. Is this supported in native android java app?

Comment: Yes. You'll have to use the material components library for this. By manipulating `BottomSheetBehavior` you'll be able to achieve what you desire.

Comment: I see. Thank you. You may answer this question, I'll mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use the material components library for this. By manipulating BottomSheetBehavior you'll be able to achieve what you desire.